# Conditional build steps depending on results

Tags: teamcity

I want to create a build step in Teamcity using Powershell, but was wondering, is there a way to put an if/else condition in Teamcity? So for example, I can use the if/else statement to read the result of the Powershell script.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you add your build step (*Runner type* = Powershell), choose *Script* = "Source code" instead of "File". That allows you to write some Powershell code in the text area, so you can manually invoke your PS script, do so conditionally, and capture its output.